# file name append with date in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to add date in my file name but it is not giving me the correct result. Here is my code.

```
dates=str(date.today())
f = open('C:Study\CSV'+dates+'output.txt','a')
f.write('\n' + results)
f.close
```

the file name is generated as **CSV2018-01-25output.txt**. how to create the file name without the word CSV?

Comment: At a guess, you'd like make the extense name of the file is 'csv'? if so , chanage it to f = open('C:Study\CSV'+dates+'output.csv','a').

Comment: I was able to  fix by giving f = open('C:Study\CSV',dates+'output.txt','a')

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
f = open('C:Study\CSV'+dates+'output.txt','a')
```

Because "CVS" in this case is your file name, i presume you wanna this:

2018-01-25output.txt

In this case try this:

```
name = 'C:Study\',dates+"output.txt"

f = open( name'a')
```